# Gatsby Lunr Plugin with Ghost source

Tags: node.js, gatsby, ghost-blog, lunrjs

Trying to implement search functionality in Gatsby with the `gastby-plugin-lunr` plugin.

My `gatsby-config.js`:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-lunr`,
  options: {
    languages: [
      {
        name: 'en'
      }
    ],
    fields: [
      { name: 'title', store: true, attributes: { boost: 20 }}
    ],
    resolvers: {
      allGhostPost: {
        title: node => node.title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But my index remains empty. Already tried to change the title node to `node.fields.title` - still didn't work.

My search component:

```
const ContactPage: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  const search = (event) => {
    const query = event.target.value;
    if (!query || !(window as any).__LUNR__) {
      setResults([]);
    }
    const lunrIndex =  (window as any).__LUNR__['en'];
    const res = lunrIndex.index.search(query);
    setResults(res);
    setQuery(query);
  };

  return (
    <Layout header={<DefaultHeader/>}>
      <input type="text" value={query} onChange={search} />
      <ul>{results.map(page => <li>{page}</li>)}</ul>
    </Layout>
  )
};
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Did you run `gatsby build` to create your index?

Comment: Yep. Index remains empty with `build` and with `develop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the `resolvers` to:

```
   resolvers: {
      GhostPost: {
        title: node => node.title
      }
    }
```